# vscode auto create a file

Tags: visual-studio-code

when I open my vscode or checkout another branch, the vscode auto create a file named Close. My question is: ***I donot want this Close file, how can I disable the Vs-code creating this Close file?*** This is not normal for vs-code behavior.

[image: close file is created by vscode]

Comment: What is your question? You've just posted a statement and an image.

Comment: sorry, I did not make myself clear. My question is: I donot want this Close file, how can I disable the Vs-code creating this Close file?